# searching an unindexed File-of-Record in pascal (Delphi 7)

Tags: delphi, search, pascal

Im creating a console app for a friend using Pascal on Delphi 7. Ive sorted adding a record and viewing them, but Im having problems in searching them. The records are stored in a .dat file. Any help would be great!

Thanks!

my code so far...

```
Type
  BookRecord = Record
    Number : Integer;
    Title  : String[50];
    Author : String[50];
    ISBN   : String[13];
  end;

Var
  Book : BookRecord;
  f    : file of BookRecord ;   

Procedure Add_Book;
Var
  Title, Author, ISBN : String;
  i : integer;
Begin
  Assign (f, 'Books.dat');
  reset (f);
  Seek (f, filesize(f));
  Book.Number := (filepos(f)+1);
  Write  ('Title:  ');
  Readln (Title);
  For i := 1 to Length(Title) do
    Title[i] := UpCase(Title[i]);
  Book.Title := Title;
  Write  ('Author: ');
  Readln (Author);
  For i := 1 to Length(Author) do
    Author[i] := UpCase(Author[i]);
  Book.Author := Author;
  Write  ('ISBN:   ');
  readln (ISBN);
  For i := 1 to Length(ISBN) do
    ISBN[i] := UpCase(ISBN[i]);
  Book.ISBN := ISBN;
  write (f, Book);
  Close (f);
End;

Procedure Show_All;
Begin
  Assign (f, 'Books.dat');
  Reset (f);
  while FilePos(f) <> FileSize(f) do
  Begin
    Read (f,book);
    Writeln ('File:   ' , Book.Number);
    Writeln ('Title:  ' , Book.Title);
    Writeln ('Author: ' , Book.Author);
    Writeln ('ISBN:   ' , Book.ISBN);
    Writeln;
  end;
  Writeln; Writeln;
  Center ('END OF FILE!');
  readln;
  Close (f);
end;

Procedure Delete_All;
Begin
  Assign (f, 'Books.Dat');
  Reset (f);
  Seek (f,0);
  Truncate (f);
  Close (f);
end;
```

Thats basically my code so far... The Add_Book, Show_All and Delete_All Procs work great, but once Ive added some records how would I go about searching for an author?

Comment: You need to be more specific. What kind of problems are you having? How are you reading the records? etc..

Comment: Since you've sorted the records, your quickest search will be with binary search. Beyond that I'd be guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your records don't appear to be sorted by author you need to use linear search. Adapt your Show_All routine to achieve this, iterating through each record looking for the author.

If you have a large database then performance will be a problem and you should consider using a real database.

Comment: Thanks, but wouldnt a linear search only show the one result? I'll look into it and see what I can figure out! Im no good with "real" databases, and its only to hold 150 or so books. Thanks!

Comment: No need for real DB with that few books. Linear search would only show one match if you chose to terminate search. For multiple matches just continue to the end, and collect all matches.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I've sorted it all out and everything is running nicely now! Cheers!

Comment: Chunky; It's a bit late in the game to start using File of Record. Consider learning about XML, INI, JSON (text is better than binary records for small data sets) and simple Database persistence is better for larger datasets as David says. As you continue to learn Delphi, its database features are a key element of the power of Delphi.  Don't bother with the BDE either.  In Delphi 7, try ibObjects and Firebird.